# oracle pl/sql arrays

Tags: arrays, oracle, plsql

i have some numbers which i want to store in an array. how will i declare array and assign value to it in oracle pl/sql??

Comment: Do you have different sets of those numbers or only one ?

Comment: i have number like 1,2,5,10,100
i want to store it in an array like array[0] = 1, array[1] = 2, ..etc
afterall i want to acces it like array[i]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are array type in PL/SQL but we can create those ourselves using the table

```
declare 
  type NumberArray is table of number index by binary_integer;
  myArray NumberArray;
begin

   myArray(0) := 1
   myArray(1) := 2 
   --or use a for loop to fill
end;
```

[The explanation article](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Oracle/Associative-Arrays-in-Oracle-PLSQL-Introduction/)

**EDIT** :

or as *Adam Musch* said if we know the data size of data, that we are operating on, we can use `VARRAYs` that are length fixed, this is `oracle` environment, so subscripts start from `1`,

Alternative is using `VARRAY`, where array subscript starts from 1 and the length of VARRAYs is fixed.

Semantic:

```
declare  type VarrayType is varray(size) of ElementType;
```

Example :

```
    declare
      type NumberVarray is varray(100) of NUMERIC(10);
      myArray NumberVarray;
    BEGIN
      myArray := NumberVarray(1,10,100,1000,10000);

      myArray(1) = 2;

      for i in myArray.first..myArray.last
      loop
        dbms_output.put_line('myArray(' || i || '): ' || myArray(i));
      end loop;  
    end;
END;
```

Output :

```
myArray(1) : 2
myArray(2) : 10
myArray(3) : 100
myArray(4) : 1000
myArray(5) : 10000
```

Comment: There is an ARRAY type in PL/SQL; it's called a VARRAY, which is a 1-indexed array with a fixed upper bound of elements.  What you're using is an associative array, which is more like a Java HashMap, where the BINARY_INTEGER is the key and the NUMBER is the value.